# My Last chance on java homework dealing with ArrayList and generic class

Tags: java

I have this homework that i've been working on. It is on inheritance which was the easy part. Then she threw in a bunch of other stuff to make it hard. It's not going to affect my grade muchthat it doesn't work all the way, but I put in a lot of time and would love to know why it does not draw the right object. I am making a collection(main picture) of pictures(shapes) in the driver than naming them by the label in the file. It all works except when I try to get the name with getName() AND draw() it always prints the last collection put into the array. I've toString'd  it to death. If anyone can solve this for me I will definitely buy you a beer.

sample text file input

```
 start picture A
 rectangle 10 50 120 30
 end picture
 start picture A
 rectangle 10 50 120 30
 end picture
 draw picture A red 10 100



  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;


public class Driver {

private static String fileName;
private static String line;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creates a list of a collection of pictures (shapes)
    ArrayList<Picture> collection = new ArrayList<Picture>();

    try {

        readLines(collection);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static void readLines(ArrayList<Picture> collection) throws Exception {

    Picture<Shape> pictures = null; // Just do null here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the file name ---> ");
    fileName = input.next();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // loop through lines
    while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("start picture")) {
            String picName = line.split(" ")[2];
            pictures = new Picture<Shape>(picName);

            pictures.setName(picName);

        } else if (line.startsWith("draw picture")) {

            String label = line.split(" ")[2];

                     //This is my PROBLEM !!! grrr

            for (Picture item : collection) {
                if (item.getName().equals(label)) {
                    pictures.draw(item);

                }
            }
        }

        else if (line.startsWith("dance picture")) {

            String label = line.split(" ")[2];

            for (Picture item : collection) {
                if (item.getName().equals(label)) {

                    pictures.dance(item);
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            txtAnalysis(line, collection, pictures);
        }
    }

    // close file
    inFile.close();

}


public static void txtAnalysis(String name, ArrayList<Picture> collection,
        Picture<Shape> pictures) {

    if (line.startsWith("circle")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

        // new object circle
        Circle c1 = new Circle("circ", x, y, z);

        // add object
        pictures.addShape(c1);

    } else if (line.startsWith("Sshape")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

        // new object MyShape
        MyShape s1 = new MyShape("myshape", x, y, z);

        // adds custom shape
        pictures.addShape(s1);

    } else if (line.startsWith("ColoredCircle")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        String color = (parts[4]);

        // new object MyShape
        ColoredCircle cc1 = new ColoredCircle("myshape", x, y, z, color);

        // add a MyShape to the picture
        pictures.addShape(cc1);

    }

    else if (line.startsWith("rectangle")) {

        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

        // new object rectangle
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("rect", x, y, z); // small and upper

        // add a rectangle to the pictures
        pictures.addShape(r1);
    }

    else if (line.startsWith("end")) {
        // adds pictures to my collection
        collection.add(pictures);

    }

    else {

    }
}
 }
```

Picture Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;



public class Picture <E extends Shape>  {
private  ArrayList<Shape> shapes;
private String name;


public Picture(String name) {

  shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
  this.name = name;

   }

public String getName() {
System.out.println("getting the name test " + name);
  return name;
 }


   public String setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return name;
   }



   public boolean addShape(E newA) {
    boolean b = shapes.add(newA);
    return b;
    }



   public void draw(Picture<E> E) {

   DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(600, 600);
   Graphics g =  panel.getGraphics();

    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
         shape.draw(g, 100, 100);



  }


}
 public void dance(Picture<E> E) {

DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(600, 600);
  Graphics g =  panel.getGraphics();

for (Shape shape : shapes) {
      shape.dance(g, 100, 100, 10, 10);



  }


}
 public String toString(String name) {

String s = "Picture " + name + " hosts these shapes:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
    s += "   "  + shapes.get(i).toString() + "\n";
}
return s;
}

}
```

Comment: It helps if you tell WHAT you are trying to accomplish buddy

Comment: And your collections is empty, which is why its not matching for you.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: I just learned about the debugger yesterday! I just ran through it and I see what is happening but I don't know why. The collection is getting the collection of pictures "A" but when it adds the second collection of pictures "B" it overwrites "A" with "B" and adds "B" so I end up with 2 identical collections "B" one in index(0) and one in index(1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your Shape class to test this, but I feel like the problem might lie in the readLines method of your Driver class.  Notice that you've placed the instantiation of the pictures variable within a while loop, so it will be rewritten every time you have a line that starts with "start picture".

Comment: The whole things smells like a procedural program wrapped in a Java class. That tends to breed bugs like this, since methods grow too long and do too much.